# graph-tools ValueError with graph_union for filtered graphs

Tags: python, debugging, graph-tool

Here's my code:

```
import graph_tool.all as gt
print gt.__version__
g1 = gt.Graph()
g1.add_vertex(5)
g1.add_edge_list([(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)])
g2 = gt.Graph()
#g2.add_vertex(3)
#g2.add_edge_list([(0,1),(1,2)])
g1.vp['prop'] = g1.new_vp('int', 1)
g1.ep['eprop'] = g1.new_ep('bool', False)
g1.ep['eprop'][list(g1.edges())[0]]=True

g1.set_edge_filter(g1.ep['eprop'], inverted=True)
#g2.vp['prop'] = g2.new_vp('int', 2)
ug = gt.graph_union(g1, g2, intersection = None, include = True, internal_props=True)
print ug
ug.list_properties()
for e in ug.edges():
    print e, ug.ep['eprop'][e]
```

I get the following output:

> 2.20 (commit f6ef9990, Fri Jan 27 16:40:08 2017 +0000) 
>   Traceback (most recent call last): 
>    File "Untitled.py", line 17, in  
>      ug = gt.graph_union(g1, g2, intersection = None, include = True, internal_props=True) 
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/generation/**init**.py", line 1192, in graph_union
>       vmask.a = not vmask.a 
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I think this may be a bug similar to [this bug](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/commit/baf6c4cc4f4430ca630e2ca93c45356be0ebb387), especially since in `gt.generation__init__.py` line 1185 has the bug fix: `emask.a = numpy.logical_not(emask.a)`, while line 1192 has the old `vmask.a = not vmask.a`.  Can anyone confirm whether this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug, and has been fixed in git.

BTW, it is better to report problems like this to the issue tracker at https://graph-tool.skewed.de/issues or the graph-tool mailing list, rather than to stack overflow, to guarantee a more speedy action.